# Are new users now unable to post answers?

Tags: discussion

Two comments by experienced users (high reputations on other SE sites) on [this popular question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/94024/are-the-social-distancing-measures-implemented-against-sars-cov-2-also-suppressi) claim they don't have sufficient reputation to post an answer.

Since this is an open question I was under the impression that anyone could answer and posted a comment to that effect. If that is not true I would like to know so that I can delete my incorrect advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[What is a “protected” or "highly active" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-or-highly-active-question)

This question was [protected](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) which means that to answer the question you must have 10 rep. Unlike pretty much every other rep-gate (maybe there are some other exceptions), *the association bonus does not count toward this limit*.

One of the uses for "protect" is when there is a string of low-quality answers coming from people without experience in a particular site and the conventions and policies of that site.

Answer (score 3):

It has been [protected](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/94024/timeline#history_3d09ef3d-e7c7-4d8a-a2a9-116c1be0a509), therefore you need to earn [10 reputation on this site](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) (having the association bonus is not enough) to post an answer.

There used to be a banner indicating this, but it's only shown if

- you don't have enough reputation to answer
- you have enough reputation (15k) to unprotect the question

That's why it's not immediately obvious to you.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers already given: The question is protected because it already has three deleted low quality answers. Hot network questions (and I think this one is one of those) attract a lot of "noise", answers from non-experienced users on a site which usually don't meet the criteria for a good answer.